# Google PubSub only handles 5 tasks at a time

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a kotlin server where we have one publisher to a certain topic, and one subscriber.
The messages we process can take up to 10 seconds to finish.

What we noticed is that no matter the amount of messages we publish, the subscriber only receives 5 tasks at a time.
Once those 5 are finished, only then it receives and starts another 5 tasks.
This is obviously too small amount of parallel tasks to process.

This is how we create the publisher:

```
fun createPublisher(topicId: String): Publisher {
    val topicName: TopicName = TopicName.of(projectId, topicId)
    return buildPublisher(topicName)
}

private fun buildPublisher(topicName: TopicName): Publisher {
    // create the topic if it doesn't exist.
    val settings = TopicAdminSettings.newBuilder()
        .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        .build()
    TopicAdminClient.create(settings).use { topicAdminClient ->
        try {
            topicAdminClient.getTopic(topicName).also {
                logger.info { "Google PubSub - got topic: ${it.name}" }
            }
        } catch (e: NotFoundException) {
            topicAdminClient.createTopic(topicName).also {
                logger.info { "Google PubSub - created topic: ${it.name}" }
            }
        }
    }

    return Publisher.newBuilder(topicName)
        .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        .build()
}
```

And then the subscriber :

```
fun runSubscriber(subId: String, topicId: String, receiver: MessageReceiver) {
        try {
            // credentials settings
            val settings = SubscriptionAdminSettings.newBuilder()
                .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build()

            // subscription details
            val topicName = TopicName.of(projectId, topicId)
            val subscriptionName = SubscriptionName.of(projectId, subId)
 val request =
                Subscription.newBuilder()
                    .setName(subscriptionName.toString())
                    .setTopic(topicName.toString())
                    // Create a pull subscription with default acknowledgement deadline of 10 seconds.
                    // Messages not successfully acknowledged within 10 seconds will get resent by the server.
                    .setAckDeadlineSeconds(10)
                    .build()

            val subscription = SubscriptionAdminClient.create(settings).use { subAdminClient ->
                try {
                    subAdminClient.getSubscription(subscriptionName)    
                } catch (e: NotFoundException) {
                    subAdminClient.createSubscription(request)
                }
            }

            // subscriber / consumer
            var sub: Subscriber? = null
            try {
                sub = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscription.name, receiver)
                    .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                    .build()

                // Start the subscriber.
                sub.startAsync().awaitRunning()

                logger.info { "Google PubSub - Listening for messages on $subscriptionName" }

            } catch (timeoutException: TimeoutException) {
                logger.error { "Google PubSub - Consumer $subId stopped due to timeout exception: $timeoutException" }
                // Shut down the subscriber after 30s. Stop receiving messages.
                sub?.stopAsync()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                logger.warn { "Google PubSub - Consumer $subId stopped due to exception: $e" }
                sub?.stopAsync()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            logger.error { "Google PubSub - runSubscriber: Consumer caught IOException: $e" }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logger.error { "Google PubSub - runSubscriber: Consumer caught Exception: $e" }
        }
    }
```

The subscriber receiver code :

```
 override fun receiveMessage(message: PubsubMessage, consumer: AckReplyConsumer) {
        val id = message.messageId
        val data = message.data.toStringUtf8()

        try {
            runBlocking {
                logger.info { "Consumer started task: $userId" }
                delay(timeMillis(seconds = 10))
                logger.info { "Consumer finished task: $userId" }
            }
        } catch (e: SerializationException) {
            logger.error { "subscriber failed to parse payload: $e" }
            Events.PostProcessingMessageReceived(messageId = message.messageId)
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            logger.error { "subscriber failed to parse payload: $e" }
            Events.PostProcessingMessageReceived(messageId = message.messageId)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logger.error { "subscriber exception: $e" }
        } finally {
            consumer.ack()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the [number of threads used to run the user callback is 5](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/7a32932fa5238e2c27479eab20fa94215fb12497/google-cloud-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Subscriber.java#L92). That is likely why you are getting only five messages at a time if you are doing blocking work in the callback. Therefore, you should either pass this blocking work to another executor or you should create the subscriber client with an [executor with more threads](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/concurrency-control).

For example, to increase to ten parallel threads, you would do something like the following:

```
      ExecutorProvider executorProvider = InstantiatingExecutorProvider.newBuilder()
          .setExecutorThreadCount(10)
          .build();
      sub = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscription.name, receiver)
                    .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                    .setExecutorProvider(executorProvider)
                    .build();
```

Another unrelated note: The comment "Messages not successfully acknowledged within 10 seconds will get resent by the server." is not correct. Since you are using the subscriber client library, it [manages leases and extends them by up to 1 hour by default](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/lease-management). If you want messages to only be outstanding for ten seconds, then you need to override the max ack extension:

```
      sub = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscription.name, receiver)
                    .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                    .setExecutorProvider(executorProvider)
                    .setMaxAckExtensionPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                    .build();
```

Comment: Thank you Kamal for the important note and the answer.
I'm not sure I understood the solution with executorProvider, does it mean that we have to spawn a thread for every task we want to handle in parallel?  So if we want to be able to handle 1,000 messages simultaneously, we need to set the executor with thread count of 1,000 ? that will blow up the application.
If so, (and in general) - how can we employ the coroutines instead of threads?
I know there is `Dispatchers.IO.asExecutor()` in kotlin, but it's not `executor provider` so is there a way to use coroutines ?

Comment: maybe I just didn't understand your first proposal ("pass work to another executor") ?

Comment: If you want to do 1000 items of blocking work at the same time, then you need 1000 threads to do that blocking work. Whether you pass 1000 into the `setExecutorThreadCount` or hand off work to a separate executor that allows for up to 1000 threads, it's the same thing. I don't know enough about Kotlin to speak to the executor model, but when I say "pass work to another executor," I basically mean "do that work asychronously rather than in the thread the callback executed in." In this case, `runBlocking` is what is blocking that thread. Can you do the work without blocking?

Comment: I can actually just make the received callback function return nothing, and meanwhile fire an asynchronous code in kotlin coroutine which will in the end call "ack".  That way it's not really 1000 threads, but rather 1000 coroutines running atop some thread pool managed by kotlin